# "Буду вынужден" українською?

Tags: переклад

Російський вираз: "Я буду вынужден скрестить с вами шпаги."

Як сказати "буду вынужден" українською?

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Зверніть увагу на четвертий пункт: вітаються питання зі спробою власного дослідження. Ви завжди можете виправити свій допис за допомогою посилання [edit]. Інакше є великий шанс, що вам просто замінусують питання або його видалять.

Comment: Зауважте, що редагування запитання зі спробою дослідження майже завжди призводить до зміни мінуса на плюс майже всіма, хто спочатку ставив мінус, або просто прибирання мінуса. Дякую за внесок, але треба попрацювати)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to show any research effort prior to asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут можна використати *складну форму* майбутнього часу:

> Я муситиму схрестити з вами шпаги